# Oracle SQL Encryption Using a Cell Value Password

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption

I am new to Oracle SQL,

And have following requirement,

There is a customer table with following columns,

```
customer (customer_id, customer_name, contact_number, credit_card_number, income, password)
```

Credit card number and the income are to be encrypted by the given password which is in the password column.

Is there any way to do this ?
I have done a extensive internet search and could not find a answer.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 2:
My encrypt_decrypt package for password column encryption

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE field_encrypt_decrypt
AS
   FUNCTION encrypt (p_plainText VARCHAR2) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC;
   FUNCTION decrypt (p_encryptedText RAW) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY encrypt_decrypt
AS
     encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES256
                                     + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_ECB
                                     + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

     encryption_key     RAW (32) := UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('01234567890123450123456789012345');

     -- The encryption key for DES algorithm, should be 8 bytes or more.

    
   /* Input plaintext to encrypt with the given key in the package */

     FUNCTION encrypt (p_plainText VARCHAR2) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC
     IS
        encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);

    /* The encryption or decryption on VARCHAR2 doesn't work directly using   DBMS_CRYPTO, therefore, convert input to RAW before encrypting it */

     BEGIN
        encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
        (
           src => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_plainText),
           typ => encryption_type,
           key => encryption_key
        );
       RETURN encrypted_raw;
     END encrypt;


     FUNCTION decrypt (p_encryptedText RAW) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
     IS
        decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
     BEGIN
        decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
        (
            src => p_encryptedText,
            typ => encryption_type,
            key => encryption_key
        );
        RETURN (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 (decrypted_raw));
     END decrypt;
END;
```

Comment: Why are you storing full credit card numbers? That's in violation of PCI regs...

Comment: What does the `password` column store? Does it store a salted hash/digest of the user's password - a reversibly-encrypted  password - or worse, their plaintext password? If so, **WHY!?!?**

Comment: Password is TDE protected, But in password column is plaintext. Sorry for the typo > interment > internet

Comment: Also I have created encryp_decrypt package to encrypt password

Comment: This is for a assignment not in real life.

Comment: If you've already created package functions to encrypt/decrypt, what are you asking? How to adapt those to pass in a key (using the password value)? We'd need to see what they are doing now, and what issue you are having supplying the key. (And I realise it's an assignment but even so... what are you going to do when the password changes? decrypt and re-encrypt the other columns?)

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole, encrypt_decrypt function is a package which only encrypt or decrypt data in password column with pre defined key. But I want is to use plaintext password of each user to encrypt income and cc no. I am posting my encrypt_decrypt pacakge in Edit 2 above

Comment: I think for "encryption_key" I can get column password value passed somehow I can create another package  will do the task, But I don't know is it possible or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to do the task,
Craeting Package therdata_encrypt_decrypt

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE otherdata_encrypt_decrypt
AS
   FUNCTION encrypt (p_plainText VARCHAR2,p_password VARCHAR2) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC;
   FUNCTION decrypt (p_encryptedText RAW,p_password VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY otherdata_encrypt_decrypt
AS
     encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES256
                                     + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_ECB
                                     + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

   /* Input plaintext to encrypt with the given key in the package */
    
     
     FUNCTION encrypt (p_plainText VARCHAR2, p_password VARCHAR2) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC
     IS
        encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);

    /* The encryption or decryption on VARCHAR2 doesn't work directly using   DBMS_CRYPTO, therefore, convert input to RAW before encrypting it */

     BEGIN
        encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
        
        (
           src => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_plainText),
           typ => encryption_type,
           /* Key Length Needs to be 32 for AES 256 Encryption Since Padding with A */
           key => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(LPAD(p_password,32,'A'))
        );
       RETURN encrypted_raw;
     END encrypt;


     FUNCTION decrypt (p_encryptedText RAW,p_password VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
     IS
        decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
     BEGIN
        decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
        
        (
            src => p_encryptedText,
            typ => encryption_type,
            /* Key Length Needs to be 32 for AES 256 Encryption Since Padding with A */
            key => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw (LPAD(p_password,32,'A'))
        );
        RETURN (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 (decrypted_raw));
     END decrypt;
END;
```

Creating a Procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CUSTOMERDEPT.insert_encrypt
(p_customer_id in customer.customer_id%TYPE,
p_customer_name in customer.customer_name%TYPE,
p_contact_number in customer.contact_number%TYPE,
p_credit_card_number in customer.credit_card_number%TYPE,
p_income in customer.income%TYPE,
p_password in customer.password%TYPE)
    IS
    
        encrypt_credit_card_no RAW(200);
        encrypt_income RAW(200);
        p_password_encrypt RAW(200);
        
        BEGIN
            
            encrypt_credit_card_no:=SYS.OTHERDATA_ENCRYPT_DECRYPT.ENCRYPT(p_credit_card_number,p_password);
            encrypt_income:=SYS.OTHERDATA_ENCRYPT_DECRYPT.ENCRYPT(p_income,p_password);
            p_password_encrypt:=SYS.ENCRYPT_DECRYPT.ENCRYPT(p_password);
        
            INSERT INTO customer(customer_id, customer_name, contact_number, credit_card_number, income, password)
            VALUES (p_customer_id,p_customer_name,p_contact_number,encrypt_credit_card_no,encrypt_income,p_password_encrypt);
            COMMIT;
    END;
```

Testing:

```
EXEC insert_encrypt (7, Test123, 0777712345, '11112223334455', '2222.22', '122122')
```